# GetProcAddress() returning null for my Hello World function

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll

Alright, so my simple DLL Hellow World function

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" void HelloWorld()
{
   MessageBox( NULL, TEXT("Hello World"), 
            TEXT("In a DLL"), MB_OK);
}
```

isn't getting called by my simple hello world app:

```
case IDM_ABOUT:

            hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(L"phantasyhook.dll");
            if (hinstDLL != NULL)
            {
                HelloWorld = (FARPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "HelloWorld");

                if (HelloWorld != NULL)
                    HelloWorld();

                else
                    MessageBox(NULL, L"is null", L"dll Error", MB_OK);

                FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);
            }

            break;
```

It opens the "is null" MessageBox, thought it should open up the Hello World one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do believe you're missing a `__declspec(dllexport)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mark that a function should be exported by a DLL for other code to be able to load it.  You can do by adding the  [__declspec(dllexport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or a [module definition file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld()
```